The Dirichlet principle and arithmetical induction
Let us consider the Dirichlet principle as follows: for all natural numbers $n > k > 0$, there is no injection from $\{0, \dots, n-1\}$ into $\{0, \dots, k-1\}$.
Is it true that in some non-standard models of PA one can define such an injection? For example, let's define $f(x)$ as $x-1$ for a non-standard number $x$, and as $x$ for a standard number $x$, where $x<n$ and $k=n-1$ for some non-standard $n$.
If so, then the Dirichlet principle is weaker than arithmetic induction.

And another question is as follows: From the Dirichlet principle (or Induction), one can obtain the following criterion: If $R$ is a finite ring (commutative with 1), then $R$ is an integral domain if and only if $R$ is a field. But can we prove the Dirichlet principle using this criterion?

According to my intuition, I think that if the induction principle does not hold, then one can determine an analogue of $\mathbb{Z}$ in arithmetic, i.e., an integral domain that is not a field. And, it is finite because it could be something like a galaxy in a non-standard model, so there exists an $N$ such that all elements in this galaxy are less than $N$.

I added a special question for this cae here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/475787/497252

The theory PA fully proves the pigeon-hole principle, which how I like to refer to your principle, the claim that there is no injection from the predecessors of $n$ to those of $n-1$. (This implies of course the weaker claim that there is no injection from $n$ to any smaller $k$.) You can easily prove this by induction on $n$, since if you had an instance of such an injection from $n$ to $n-1$, then you could make a smaller instance by omitting one point on each side. So there can be no least counterexample. So every model of PA satisfies the pigeon-hole principle.
Indeed, the axiom scheme of induction is equivalent to the pigeon-hole principle. If we have the PHP, then I claim every definable nonempty set has a least number, which is one way of stating the induction scheme. For if $\varphi(N)$ holds for some $N$ but there is no least such $N$, then let $f(x)=x-1$ if there is some $y<x$ with $\varphi(y)$, and otherwise $f(x)=x$. This is injective from $N$ to $N-1$, precisely because $\varphi$ has no least instance.
Meanwhile, as you mention, every nonstandard model of PA admits such injections as externally definable functions. These will not be definable inside the model, but definable externally from the standardness predicate. Simply let $f(x)=x-1$ for all nonstandard $x$ and $f(n)=n$ for standard $n$. This provides a uniform injective map of $N$ into $N-1$ for any nonstandard number $N$.

So, if $X$ is a set without a least element, then we map an element $x\in X$ to an element $y$ defined as follows: $(y < x) \land ( y \in X) \land \forall z > y,; (z \in X) \to z \geq x)$. Then we cut X and {0,...,,N-1} to make a finite domain of this injection. But how can we prove that such an element $y$ exists? Maybe I'm not understanding the definition of a 'finite set' or something else?

The induction principle of PA applies to definable properties, expressible in the first-order language of arithmetic, which allows ${+,\cdot,0,1,<}$ and basic logic, including quantifiers. If a formula $\varphi(x)$ has instances but no least instance in some model of arithmetic with the pigeon-hole principle, then let $N$ be any particular instance $\varphi(N)$, and map each $x\leq N$ to the largest $y$ below $x$ with $\varphi(y)$. There is such a $y$, because $\varphi$ had no least instance. Map all other $x$ to $x$. This gives an injection from $N$ to $N-1$.

You are right that we need to know that there will be a largest $y$, but this is a consequence of PHP as follows: if there is no largest $y$ below $x$ with $\varphi(y)$, then simply substract $1$ while above them all, and otherwise identity. This is injective.

Indeed, that makes things easier, to just do it that way in the first place. That is, fix $N$ with $\varphi(N)$ but no least instance. Now define $f(x)=x-1$, if there is any $y<x$ with $\varphi(y)$, and otherwise $f(x)=x$. This is injective from $N$ to $N-1$. I'm going to edit to use this simpler definition.

Ah, yeah, exactly, I see. Super )
